# How do i convert this to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Im having a problem converting this to mysqli from mysql, i've attempted what the php documentation said but i still can't get it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE (username = '$username' OR email = '$username') AND password = '$password'"), 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
```

I tried this:

```
return (mysqli_data_seek(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE (username = '$username' OR email = '$username') AND password = '$password'"), 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
```

Whole function:

```
function login($username, $password){
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","frostbase");
    $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);


    $username = sanitize($username);
    $password = md5($password);

    return (mysqli_data_seek(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE (username = '$username' OR email = '$username') AND password = '$password'"), 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: what did you try? what was the result?

Comment: `mysqli_result(mysqli_query`

Comment: Read the manual properly.

Comment: mysqli function differs in that they require the connection parameter, unlike the mysql set of functions

Comment: Sheesh. They closed Kenny. So here it goes as a comment. You can do it way better actually, using [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql#safemysql): 
`$sql = SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE (username = ?s OR email = ?s) AND password = ?s";
return (bool)$db->getOne($sql, $username, $username, $password);`

Comment: @user2067005 Post the function you are returning from and will re open the question

Comment: I bet YCS wants to say that this question is badly worded and pretty localized - and indeed it is. No specific error messages are given for example which should be the first thing to educate the user about so the user is able to get self-help and stuff.

Comment: no error messages are given

Answer (score 0):

You can do it way better actually.

[safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql#safemysql) is a tool that helps you to convert your ugly old mysql API-based code not to new ugly mysqli API-based code but use way better approach.

The point is that you must not use raw API calls in the application code, be it `mysql`, `mysqli` or `PDO`. But wrap them in a library that will do all the required operations like data binding, fetching, error handling, profiling and many more.

Frankly, you have only to write your query - the rest is done by the lib:

```
$sql = "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE (username = ?s OR email = ?s) AND password = ?s"; 
return (bool)$db->getOne($sql, $username, $username, $password);
```

or, in a form of a function

```
function login($username, $password){
    global $con; // you have to connect ONCE per application
    $sql = "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE (username = ?s OR email = ?s) AND password = ?s"; 
    return (bool)$con->getOne($sql, $username, $username, $password); 
}
```

Comment: I keep getting this error:Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::getOne() in C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\frostbase\core\functions\users.php on line 253